# Simpler version of Egorov's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Here you can find a simpler version of Egorov's theorem and its proof. While studying its proof, I couldn't understand why the sets $\{|f(x)-f_k (x)| < \varepsilon \},\ (k>m)$ are measurable. Thanks in advance.
[image: Question]

Edit: The hypothesis mentioned in the lemma:
$\{ f_k \}$ is a sequence of measurable functions that converges to almost everywhere in a set $E$ of finite measue to a finite limit $f$.
"Almost everywhere" means that it holds for everywhere in $E$ except for possibly a subset $Z \subset E$ of measure zero.

Comment: Since each $f_k$ is measurable, so is the limit $f$. Hence $g = f-f_k$ is measurable. But then the absolute value of g is also measurable, and by definiton of measurable function, the set $\{|g| \le \epsilon\}$ is measurable for each $k$. Finally $E_m$ is measurable being a countable intersection of measurable sets.

Comment: @Peanut Thank you very much!

Comment: @Peanut : You should write your comment as an answer if it solved this question.